# How to create a avd using skins in android?

Tags: android

I have updated my sdk and i dont know how to create a Avd using skins in android after updating the sdk (though i had previously created one avd before updating the sdk ).I have downloaded the skin(for Galaxy S2) and placed them in the E:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-17\skins folder.However in the Windows->Android Virtual Device->New->Skin does not show under targets the Galaxy_S2 avd.Can any one suggest me how do i go about it?Following is the screen shot.

[image]